# Android studio showing continuous same error

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

[It is an image which is showing errors that I want to solve

I am using android 2.3.3 I have changed many setups but some constant problems are apearing

1. Gradle project sync failed.
2. Rendor errors
3. install repository and sync project.

I do a lot search and found some ways I replace gradle folder with new version of gradle but failed to solve this.As i installed repository but error is still there.

Why all setups of android are showing same problem?

Comment: You may want to include the error messages in your question. I would also suggest you deal with each issue in a separate question instead of trying to fix all your issues in one.

Comment: connected to internet while sync?

Comment: yeah it connected to internet all time

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all previous installation.
2. Install java JDK 8.
3. Install jre.
4. Download latest Android studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)
5. Follow these steps. (https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

Can you specify your system configurations?

Comment: I removed all previous installation and installed all these things newly. System specifications 4GB Ram ,i3 1.7Ghz,500 gb hard,windows 10 as OS.